# How to enable user's systemd timers and services for Grive2?

Tags: services, systemd, systemd-logind

I have installed [Grive2 console client](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2) for Google Drive with the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install grive
```

Then I created folder for sync and log-in to my Google account:

```
mkdir ~/GoogleDrive
cd GoogleDrive
grive -a
```

Then I reboot my system, and can't find any services for `grive`.
So I tried to investigate the file list installed by `grive` package:

```
$ dpkg -L grive
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/grive
/usr/lib/grive/grive-sync.sh
/usr/lib/systemd
/usr/lib/systemd/user
/usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-changes@.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-timer@.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-timer@.timer
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/grive
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/grive
/usr/share/doc/grive/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/grive/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
```

Here are 3 interesting `systemd`-related items:

```
$ dpkg -L grive | grep systemd/user/
/usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-changes@.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-timer@.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-timer@.timer
```

Their contents are as follows:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-changes@.service
[Unit]
Description=Google drive sync (changed files)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/grive/grive-sync.sh listen "%i"
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-timer@.service
[Unit]
Description=Google drive sync 
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/grive/grive-sync.sh sync "%i"

$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/user/grive-timer@.timer
[Unit]
Description=Google drive sync (fixed intervals)

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/5
OnBootSec=3min
OnUnitActiveSec=5min
Unit=grive-timer@%i.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

So it seems that `grive` has internal functionality to automate synchronization.
And there is no need to invent another bicycle with `cron` scheduler.

But I'm not familiar with `systemd` user's timers and services.

Found [forum post on ArchLinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191546#p1488318), but can't understand how to combine it with grive files.

What should I do to enable `grive` services and timers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question was giving me the right hint to look at the accompanying systemd user timer/service of grive2.

Only recently the answer to your question was added to the README.md on [grive2 github repository](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2). Have a look at [README section on systemd-based syncs](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2#scheduled-syncs-and-syncs-on-file-change-events). Essentially you call:

```
# 'google-drive' is the name of your Google Drive folder in your $HOME directory
systemctl --user enable grive-timer@$(systemd-escape google-drive).timer
systemctl --user start grive-timer@$(systemd-escape google-drive).timer
systemctl --user enable grive-changes@$(systemd-escape google-drive).service
systemctl --user start grive-changes@$(systemd-escape google-drive).service
```

Regards

RA

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.